# How do I format tabs in Blueprint CSS?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I've inserted an image below showing were I currently stand (css version) and where I want to be (tabled based version).

I originally created this layout with tables and I would like to move to a css based version.  I have a long way to go.

I'm using Blueprint CSS.

Current issues:

- There is a gap between the tabs that I'd like to get rid of.  How do I get rid of this gap?
- I would like to put more padding inside each tab.  How do I do this without pushing the tabs onto the next line?

[image: https://lh3.ggpht.com/_wyoBVbEFXVg/SZRAGMj-ocI/AAAAAAAAAqw/O6T987pw6Dw/cssVsTable.gif]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Heatmap using BluePrint</title>
    <!-- Framework CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/heatmap/styles/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css"
        media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/heatmap/styles/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css"
        media="print">
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/heatmap/styles/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">

    body{font-size:70%;font-family:Verdana, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:5px;}    
    table.heatmap td {border: 1px solid black;}
    table.heatmap{border-collapse:collapse;}

    a {color:black;text-decoration: none;}
    a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

    .list-as-tabs
    {
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    .list-as-tabs, .list-as-tabs li
    {
        display: inline;

    }

    .hover-links
    {
        background-color:#fffdbf;
    }
    .hover-links li a:hover
    {
        background-color:yellow;    
    }    
    table.heatmap tr td {text-align:center;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="span-20">
            <div class="prepend-5 span-10">
                <h3>
                    Issuer Heatmap</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="span-5 last">
                <ul class="list-as-tabs">
                    <li><a href="javascript:popUp('legend.htm')">Legend</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/heatmap/default.aspx?level=heatmap&feedback=true"><img src="/heatmap/images/lightbulb.gif" alt="Send Feedback about Heatmap." /></a></li>
                    <li><input type="image" src="/heatmap/images/excel-mini.gif" alt="Export Heatmap to Excel." /></li>
                    <li><a href="print.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="/heatmap/images/printer.gif" alt="Print this page." /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="prepend-5 span-15 last">
                <ul class="list-as-tabs hover-links">
                    <li><a href="#">View Draft Heatmap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Security</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit Heatmap and Platforms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">View Revision History</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "gap"? I'm not sure I can see what you mean in the screen grab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no gap between tabs in the screenshot you posted.

As for adding padding to the tabs, you can do this:

```
.list-as-tabs li a {
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

That gives the link top and bottom padding of 3px and left and right padding of 5px. This is nice because it gives you a bigger click target.

You state that you don't want to wrap but from what I can tell on the screenshot, there simply isn't enough room. You'll either have to make the font smaller or use shorter phrases for the tabs. Maybe this?

```
<ul class="list-as-tabs hover-links">
    <li><a href="#">Draft Heatmap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Edit Heatmap/Platforms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Revision History</a></li>
</ul>
```